# VB.NET: Determine delimiter in input text string

Tags: vb.net, string, text, textbox, delimiter

Is there any way to actively scan a text box to search for key delimiters?  I'm looking for the delimiters:  vbNewLine, comma, colon, semicolon, and space.

Once the user pastes their delimited string, how can I have VB.net determine which character is delimiting?

Example:

input string:  "aaa,bbb,ccc"

I want to be able to scan that text and know that the delimiter is ","

Same for "aaa;bbb;ccc", will be ";"

Could be any number of values between the delimiters

Comment: And what's the criteria? In a string of 3 characters `;, `, which one should be considered a delimiter?

Comment: Sorry, added more details

Comment: Ok, what if it's `aaa;bbb,ccc`?

Comment: If inconclusive, then ignore.  This is a feature meant to speed up a process.  If the string contains multiple possible delimiters, the user will select, using a DDL, which character they want to use to delimit.

Comment: What if it's `"a,b";bbb;ccc` ? Note - this is a valid `;`-delimited string.

Comment: Then ignore once again.  I can't think of any situation where that would be the case, however.  Like I said, this is just an efficiency process to automatically detect what the user intends to split the string using.  Since the currently most popular input method is by new lines, it will default to that method if it's not uniformly delimited.  I appreciate your thoroughness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use following class for this, the `ClosestDelimiter` gives you the delimiter that has the most chance of matching (in case it doesn't find what it's looking for, it will throw an error, be warned :))

I also added a `Parse` method that returns an array of the single items (could contain empty strings in case a delimiter comes up directly after the previous delimiter eg: ;A;;C;;D)

And finally a `TryParse` method, that returns true or false, and catches the exceptions for you, updated result to Nothing when parsing failed

```
Public Class DelimiterScanner
    Private delimiters() As String = {vbNewLine, ",", ";", ":", " "}

    Public Function ClosestDelimiter(row As String) As String
        Dim maxUsages As Integer = 0
        Dim multiplePossibilities As Boolean = False
        Dim current As Integer
        Dim delimiter As String = Nothing

        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Row cannot be an empty string", "row")
        End If

        For Each del As String In delimiters
            current = row.Split({del}, StringSplitOptions.None).Count
            If current > maxUsages Then
                delimiter = del
                maxUsages = current
                multiplePossibilities = False
            ElseIf current > 0 AndAlso current = maxUsages Then
                multiplePossibilities = True
            End If
        Next
        If multiplePossibilities Then
            Throw New FormatException("Multiple delimiters have the same length")
        End If
        If maxUsages = 0 Then
            Throw New FormatException("No delimiters found in row")
        End If
        Return delimiter
    End Function

    Public Function Parse(row As String, Optional useDelimiter As String = Nothing) As String()
        Dim selectedDelimiter As String = useDelimiter
        Dim result() As String = Nothing

        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row) Then
            ' don't parse empty strings
            Throw New ArgumentException("Cannot parse an empty input value", row)
        End If
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedDelimiter) Then
            ' get delimiter if no basic is given
            selectedDelimiter = ClosestDelimiter(row)
        End If
        result = row.Split({selectedDelimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function TryParse(row As String, ByRef result() As String, Optional useDelimiter As String = Nothing) As Boolean
        Dim succeeded As Boolean = True

        Try
            result = Parse(row, useDelimiter)
        Catch ex As Exception
            result = Nothing
            succeeded = False
        End Try
        Return succeeded

    End Function
End Class
```

**UPDATE**

As an example, you can use the class like this (here you see the main method for my console class). We first initiate the class new, and then check if it is parse-able with the `TryParse` method, when not, the parse is invalid, and the delimiter cannot be determined yet. If it was valid, you can call the `ClosestDelimiter` method, and you can also assume that your result contains the correct strings.

I also made an update still on the SplitMethod, as i have to take into account that we want to split on strings, and not on separate chars (eg: VbNewLine), i also corrected this in the code above

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dScanner As New DelimiterScanner()
    Dim result() As String = Nothing
    Dim tests() As String = {String.Empty, "a,b;c", "aaa,bbb,ccc;", "a;b;c;;;;d", "this is a test;working;online;stackoverflow;", "aaa" + vbNewLine + "bbb" + vbNewLine + "ccc"}

    For Each testItem In tests
        Console.WriteLine("Trying to parse {0}", testItem)
        If dScanner.TryParse(testItem, result) Then
            Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "- Results (joined with ,): {0}", String.Join(",", result))
            Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "- Used delimited: {0}", dScanner.ClosestDelimiter(testItem))
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "- Delimiter cannot be found!")
        End If
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

And output would then be the following:

```
Trying to parse
        - Delimiter cannot be found!
Trying to parse a,b;c
        - Delimiter cannot be found!
Trying to parse aaa,bbb,ccc;
        - Results (joined with ,): aaa,bbb,ccc;
        - Used delimited: ,
Trying to parse a;b;c;;;;d
        - Results (joined with ,): a,b,c,,,,d
        - Used delimited: ;
Trying to parse this is a test;working;online;stackoverflow;
        - Results (joined with ,): this is a test,working,online,stackoverflow,
        - Used delimited: ;
Trying to parse aaa
bbb
ccc
        - Results (joined with ,): aaa,bbb,ccc
        - Used delimited:
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, Icepickle!  This looks great.  Is there any way this can be adjusted to work within a `Private Sub txtInput_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtInput.TextChanged`?

Comment: What would you like it to do at that time? What is stopping you from using the class directly in the event?

Comment: I'd like it to be in the textchanged event to automatically pick up how the pasted text is delimited.  This will then use the output of your logic to automatically select the relevant delimiter-method from a dropdown.  Example:  Your logic determines the pasted string is delimited by ",", so it selects the index in the Drop down for ",".  I'm still kind of new at programming, but I can figure out the logistics if you can point me in the right direction of how to call this class from within the TextChanged event.  Please let me know if unclear, and thanks again!

Comment: I added an example on how you can use the class ;)

Comment: This is perfect!  I was able to tweak your example code to where it works like a charm.  Thanks again!